# Rerender sibling component in React

Tags: reactjs, siblings, rerender

I am new to React. I am stuck on this problem for days now.
I have got a parent component which wraps two sibling components, "FileUpload" and "Documents"

The "FileUpload" is for uploading a file and "Documents" is for displaying all the uploaded files.

I want the "Documents" rerender after a new file is uploaded via "FileUpload", so that it shows the new file in the UI.

What would be the best approach to achieve this ?

Below is the code I have written so far for the sibling components:

```
 FileUpload:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const FileUpload = (props) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setFiles(e.target.files);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      // console.log(files);
      data.append("file", files[i]);
    }

    data.append("parentDbId", props.parentDbId);
    data.append("parentObject", props.parentObject);
    //console.log(data);

    try {
      await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      //  action="http://localhost:5000/upload"
      //  method="POST"
      //encType="multipart/form-data"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <div className="row mb-3">
        <div className="col-lg-4">
          <label htmlFor="formFileMultiple" className="form-label mb-0">
            Add files
          </label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="file"
            id="formFileMultiple"
            name="file"
            multiple
            onChange={onInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 mt-0 gx-0">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
            Upload
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;

====================================================================

Documents:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Documents = (props) => {
  const parentDbId = props.parentDbId;

  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

  //mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("first use effect");
    loadDocuments();
  }, []);

  const loadDocuments = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/documents/${parentDbId}`
    );
    setDocuments(result.data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        {documents.map((document, index) => (
          <div className="col-lg-3" key={index}>
            <a href={document.filePath}>{document.fileName}</a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Documents;
```

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just have the parent control document state and pass the state and callback down to the children as a prop. Now the siblings are referencing the same state and will be re-rendered when props (ie document state) changes. The parent can also handle the data fetching and uploading.
it will look like this:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  ...do data fetching here
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(async () => {}, []); // You might want to reset document state here?

  return (
    <div>
      <Docs documents={documents} />
      <Upload onUpload={setDocuments} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wonder if you should actually have two documents components, one for displaying the files being uploaded, and one for displaying the already uploaded files. You would embed one within the Upload component and the other would fetch documents from the api every time `onUpload` completes